# Method efficiency for zero_sum?(array) #basic Ruby language bootcamp entrance prep

Tags: ruby

I am working through a one line solution for the question #write a boolean function zero_sum? that takes an array of integers and returns true if 2 elements in the array sum to zero.

Here is my original answer that would also work if they would ask for a return of the indicies, but I am having trouble coming up with a one line function that works.

```
def zero_sum?(array)
  array.each_with_index do |x, i1|
    for i2 in i1 + 1..array.length - 1
      if x + array[i2] == 0
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  false
end

puts "\nZero Sum:\n" + "*" * 15 + "\n"
puts zero_sum?([1, -1]) == true
puts zero_sum?([1,1,0,2,1]) == false
puts zero_sum?([1,1,0,2,1,0]) == true
puts zero_sum?([2,3,4,-3,1]) == true
```

Here is my one line solution. I am not getting any false returns at all:

```
def zero_sum?(array)
  array.any? {|x| array.each {|y| array.count(0) != 1 && x + y == 0}}
end

puts "\nZero Sum:\n" + "*" * 15 + "\n"
puts zero_sum?([1, -1]) == true
puts zero_sum?([1,1,0,2,1]) == false  #returning true 
puts zero_sum?([1,1,2,1]) == false  #returning true
puts zero_sum?([1,1,0,2,1,0]) == true
puts zero_sum?([2,3,4,-3,1]) == true
```

Any insight would be great! (if a one line response for the return of indices comes to mind, that would be awesome!).

Comment: I suppose you could also order the array by absolute value, and then just check adjacent pairs to see if they sum to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
require 'set'

def zero_sum?(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Set.new) do |n,st|
    return true if st.include?(-n)
    st << n
  end
  false
end

zero_sum? [1,-1]        #=> true
zero_sum? [1,1,0,2,1]   #=> false
zero_sum? [1,1,0,2,1,0] #=> true
zero_sum? [2,3,4,-3,1]  #=> true
```

I've made `st` a set rather than an array to speed lookups.

Comment: Would using `each_with_object(Set.new)` be better here?

Comment: I really like how this handles the case of two or more `0`s, very clever. Also just another query, how about converting the parameter `arr` to a set and using a regular empty array `[]` as the parameter to `each_with_object`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, I don't see how converting `arr` to a set would help, unless it's just to remove duplicates, in which `uniq` would be more direct. Either way, `return true if arr.count(0) > 1` would have to be executed first. You'd have to benchmark to see if that's faster. Counting zeroes and then creating the set would take some time. It still seems more efficient for `each_with_object`'s argument to be an empty set rather than an empty array. Please correct me if I've missed your point.

Comment: Yes I think I misunderstood why you used a set in the first place, so poor suggestion from myself. You do actually give the reason for using a set in your answer. So generally if I'm searching/looking-up something in a list of unique elements, is it a good idea to consider using sets over arrays?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, I'll go with the stock answer: yes if the list is large and performance is important.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this using [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
def zero_sum? arr
  arr.combination(2).any? { |pair| pair.inject(:+).zero? }
end

zero_sum? [2,3,5,2,1,-2,4]    #=> true
zero_sum? [2,3,5,2,1,2,4]     #=> false
zero_sum? [2,3,5,0,0,2,1,2,4] #=> true
```

Caveat about this answer being that `Array#combination` is expensive, so there's probably a better way. But interesting to know this approach nonetheless.

*Many thanks to @Ursus for pointing out using `any?` instead of `find`.*

Comment: What about 
`arr.combination(2).any? { |pair| pair.inject(:+).zero? }`

Comment: @Ursus, nice one then that returns the boolean. I will update my answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your one line solution is that because the `any?` and `each` loops iterate over the whole array if a zero sum isn't found earlier then each element will be added to itself at some point. This means that if the array contains a 0 you'll get a `0 + 0 == 0` comparison.

I won't spoil finding a one liner for you, but if you'd like to work on finding a solution that is similar to your multiline solution then you can obtain the index of the current element whilst still using `any` by creating an `Enumerator` and using `with_index` i.e.

```
array.to_enum.with_index.any? { |x, index| ... }
```

and you can access the remainder of the array using slice notation:

```
array[index + 1..array.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a one-liner, another approach is to use [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) with parallel assignment to get two arrays, the positives and negatives of a number list `arr`.

```
def zero_sum? arr
  return true if arr.count(0) > 1
  a, b = arr.uniq.partition(&:positive?)
  a.any? { |e| b.include? -e }
end

zero_sum? [2,3,5,2,1,-2,4]    #=> true
zero_sum? [2,3,5,2,1,2,4]     #=> false
zero_sum? [2,3,5,0,0,2,1,2,4] #=> true
```

Other key methods: [Numeric#positive?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Numeric.html#method-i-positive-3F), [Array#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) and [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)